# Как исправить ошибку чтоб корректно выводилось наименование возраста, по введенной цифре возраста?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
age = int(input())
 
agesMapping = {
    'Младенец': range(0, 1),
    'Малыш': range(2, 3),
    'Ребенок': range(4, 11),
    'Подросток': range(12, 18),
    'Взрослый человек': range(19, 64),
    'Пожилой человек': range(65, 100),
}

 
print(agesMapping[age-1])
```

Comment: Эх... Моего дедушку обделили. Его даже в списке нет. ;)

Comment: :) наверное ему больше 100 лет. Долгожитель.

Comment: @GrAnd. В своем варианте поправил )

Comment: @Muriam совсем не обязательно 100, может быть и 64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К примеру такой вариант

```
age = int(input())
 
agesMapping = {
    'Младенец': range(0, 2),
    'Малыш': range(2, 4),
    'Ребенок': range(4, 12),
    'Подросток': range(12, 19),
    'Взрослый человек': range(19, 65),
    'Пожилой человек': range(65, 101),
}

for k, v in agesMapping.items():
    if age in v:
        print(k)
```

Вам необходимо проитерироваться по словарю и провести сравнение. Так же рекомендую сдвинуть range на 1 вправо, как привел я, тогда вы будете попадать в диапазон.

Answer (score 3):

Поменяйте местами возраст и наименование.

```
def split_list_key(agesMapping):  # Не желательно использовать если вам нужно изменять значения словаря
    """Функция разделяет кортежи ключей и каждому даёт значение всего кортежа"""
    tmp = {}
    for key, item in agesMapping.items():
        for i in key:
            tmp[i] = item
    return tmp


age = int(input())

agesMapping = {range(0, 2): 'Младенец',
               range(2, 4): 'Малыш',
               range(4, 12): 'Ребенок',
               range(12, 19): 'Подросток',
               range(19, 65): 'Взрослый человек',
               range(65, 100): 'Пожилой человек'}

agesMapping = split_list_key(agesMapping)

# Замечание, функция range() не берёт верхнюю границу, в итоге появляются пробелы в числах
print(agesMapping[age - 1])
```

Функция меняющая местами ключи и объекты

```
def exchange_dict(agesMapping):
    tmp = {}
    for i in agesMapping:
        tmp[agesMapping[i]] = i
    return tmp
```

Comment: "Функция меняющая местами ключи и объекты" делается проще. Если точнее, тут и функция-то не нужна.  `y = {v,k for k,v in x}` (где `x` - исходный словарь)

Comment: Если не рассматривать функцию exchange_dict, а рассматривать только первый кусок кода, точно ли верно в принте? Почему-то выдается ошибка.

Comment: Да, действительно, моя программа работает не корректно, изменил ответ @Muriam

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

*Доброшу вариант*

```py
age = int(input())

agesMapping = {
    'Младенец': range(0, 2),
    'Малыш': range(2, 4),
    'Ребенок': range(4, 12),
    'Подросток': range(12, 19),
    'Взрослый человек': range(19, 65),
    'Пожилой человек': range(65, 101),
}

(age_str, *_), = filter(
    lambda x: age in x[1], 
    agesMapping.items()
)
print(age_str)
```